# Do I have to specify a 'to' recipient?

Tags: mailgun, bcc

When I'm sending email via mailgun, must I specify a 'to' recipient?

In some cases, I'd prefer to specify only 'Bcc' recipients.

---

**EDIT**: I've already tried to do this on my own and I receive a

```
'Bad Request - 'to' parameter is missing' error.
```

I just wanted to know if there's another way around this, because typically you can send an email without a 'To' recipient, so long as you specify a CC or Bcc recipient.

Comment: then it's probably an api restriction. use yourself as the To:, or a dedicated junk address which just dumps the mail to /dev/null.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28503099/109941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not send mail only using `bcc`.  There is a trick I use in which I make the from and to the same address (something like `info@mydomain.com`) and then fill up the bcc slot with whatever I need.

You may send mail using mailing lists that does not require you to expose other email addresses.

https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-mailinglists.html

Comment: Can we specify an empty mailing list? Because if I am sending mails in 10 batches, the mail address in to will get the mail 10 times... So, to avoid that, it is a good alternative?

Comment: @ptmdevncoder You may not specify an empty `to` which is why you use your own email as a `to` email.  This way it doesn't matter how many emails go to the dummy email.

Comment: I did not say an empty TO. I meant to say, adding a valid mailing list created at mailgun end but with 0 entries in it. Making it an empty mailing list. But, the TO field won't be empty due to the presence of that empty mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, the SMTP call is being translated to a call to the SMTP provided which is usually not forced to have a 'to' recipient, but the best way is to perform a test where you send an email with only 'bcc' recipient (you can send it to yourself as a test'

Comment: OK. Another workaround (beside the mailing list option) is to have the sender email address also in the 'to' list.